# Things to consider while picking domain name?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

We want to buy a domain name for our company. But all of the domain name we've discussed has already taken by some one else.

Is it good to use trailing character to existing domain name so we have available domain name to register.

E.g for:

- example.com
- example1.com
- myexample.com

or using long domain name like:

- companyandproductname.com
- bestproductname.com
- my-product-name.com

And also, is there any other thing to consider while picking domain name other than using company name and / or product on domain name?  What is the advantage and disadvantage?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not care much about EMD 'Exact Matching Domains' so its pretty much pointless using a long domain with company and product name.

**Branding or Short Business Names**

Google wants businesses using proper branding and not just labeling for search engines. So you should use companyname.com or the branding name.

**Google Doesn't Want**

As i've mentioned early Google nowadays wants branding, what this means is no longer does Google reward for keywords used in domain names, too many keywords can even flag your site and be reward less for those keywords. Aim for Keywords in the URL, that's what SEO friendly URLS are for.

**Long Business Names are naff to look at, never mind type**

If you were to have a company called Dorset Innovation Plumbing Professionals then realistically this is just far to long and you could opt to use a branding label such as 'DIPP.co.uk' or something on those lines. Nowadays businesses are coming up with the branding and businesses names based on the availability of domain names before they even start their business plan, long domains look naff and impossible for people to correctly remember, that's why in my honest opinion short business names or branding.

Comment: Yah google maybe doesnt care :D . Thanks 
But my problem is mycompanyname.com is already take by some one else . 
Well maybe some acronym would  helps. Let me check for domain availibility. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: What's the business name if you mind me asking, and whats your target region, nation, or is it international?

Comment: I dont mind for you to know my company name, but i could find a good way to send it privately to you.

Comment: What domain type are you looking for? .co.uk, .net? .com? etc

Comment: I personaly prefer .com as it stand for commercial . FYI. My product is traditional apparel. 
I discovered that mycomanyname.co.uk is available but we are not based in UK an will not reach UK market in short time. 
But other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Well you can consider a .net or .org - 99.9% people on this planet don't even know the different between them nor what .com stands for. though of course they know the .com is the most popular and co.uk is for UK but .net .org is just as good, people don't really look at your TLD type when clicking in Google but is handy if they remember it.

Comment: .org is available. 
Wouldn't it look unprofesional if we use .org for selling things for money ? (it will use this site generaly for online shop) 
Sory i'm quite new in domain name picking and marketing . So i dont know what user thinking.

Answer (score 1):

As you are thinking about a company name website, I suggest you stick to one with no trailing characters or EMDs or domain names with hyphens.

Trailing characters reduce the authority of your domain name. How shall you feel like if Google had its domain name as google1.com ? You need your domain name to be short and crispy. Longer ones tend to stay shorter in your users' minds.

If the com domain name is taken, try searching for a different domain name extension. If not, I suggest you seek a different domain name.

Comment: *"You need your domain name to be short and crispy. Longer ones tend to stay shorter in your users' minds."* — what is your source for that?

Comment: Which shall be easy for you - google.com or ilovemygooglewebsite.com?

Comment: As I said, what is your source that longer ones are more easily forgettable? Your reply is besides the point, there are countless considerations when picking a domain name; even the original question asked about that: *"is there any other thing to consider while picking domain name other than using company name ... ?"*